# How should I depict "User wants to see his profile" in a Dataflow Diagram? Maybe I shouldn't?

Tags: oop, uml, dataflow-diagram

I have a `User` that wants to see his online profile, in a site where he previously has registered at. I am in charge of making a Dataflow Diagram out of this situation. I know for sure that the `System` will return a `Profile`. That is why I put an arrow from `System` to `User`.

How can I express that the `User` is requesting his profile to the `System`? I can't think of a way of expressing that in a DFD. I guess it's maybe because you are only supposed to show data flow in a DFD and not actions/requests? Should I completly erase the arrow that goes from `User` to `System`(`?See his profile?`) ?

```
Context Diagram (Level 0 Dataflow Diagram)
```

[image]

```
Level 1 Dataflow Diagram
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hard and fast answer to this.  It's possible to argue against including it (could be considered a control flow, not a dataflow).  However, assuming purpose of DFD is for human understanding (i.e. it's a picture to look at) go with what makes most sense to your audience.

If I were drawing it, I'd include the input flow on both L0 & L1 (probably named `View Profile` rather than `Check his profile` - I prefer imperative statements). It's both the event that triggers action, and will also likely carry data to identify the user.

I wouldn't however include the flow marked `???` on the L1 diagram.  Reason: you're pulling data from a datastore so the query is implicit.

hth.